# How do I get a straight-line Linear Regression result in Pyspark?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, data-science

I am running a simple linear regression on a very small dataset using Pyspark but cannot get it to return a straight-line result, as it does in scikit-learn, keras, and tensorflow. I have tried hundreds of parameters and settings using a hyper-parameter search. (My code is below). I have also tried using a LinearRegressionWithSGD and get the same result. All I need is a single straight-line result. How do I get this in Pyspark ?

```
def plotData(xs, ys, predictions, labels, the_title):
    y_preds = list( (predictions.collect()) )
    x_labels = list( (labels.collect()) )
    print('xs = ', xs)
    print('ys = ', ys)
    print('y_predictions = ' , y_preds)

    # Plot outputs
    plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))    
    plt.axis([min(xs)-1, max(xs)+1, min(ys)-1, max(ys)+1])  
    plt.title(the_title)
    plt.scatter(x_labels, ys, color='blue')
    plt.plot(x_labels, y_preds, 'rx')
    plt.plot(x_labels, y_preds, color='black', linewidth=3)
    plt.xlabel('x values', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('y values', fontsize=14)
    plt.show()

# Small contrived dataset
dataset = [(1, 1), (2, 3), (4, 3), (3, 2), (5, 5)]

dataset2 = []
xs = []
ys = []
for d in dataset:
    xs.append(d[0])
    ys.append(d[1])
    dataset2.append((d[0], Vectors.dense([d[1]])))

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("LinearRegTest").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(dataset2, ["label", "features"])  

i=100 
r=0.3
e=0.8
s='auto'
f=True

# Create linear regression model
lir = LinearRegression(maxIter=i, regParam=r, elasticNetParam=e, solver=s, fitIntercept=f)

# Train the model using our training data
model = lir.fit(df) 

# Generate some predictions using our model 
fullPredictions = model.transform(df).cache()

# Extract the predictions and the "known" correct labels.
predictions = fullPredictions.select("prediction").rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])
labels = fullPredictions.select("label").rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])

print("Coefficients: " + str(model.coefficients))
print("Intercept: " + str(model.intercept))
print("Total iterations: " + str(model.summary.totalIterations))  
paramStr = "maxIter="+str(i)+", regParam="+str(r)+", elasticNetParam="+str(e) +", solver="+str(s)+", fitIntercept="+str(f)   

plotData(xs, ys, predictions, labels, "Contrived Dataset: LinearRegression CHART " + "\n" + paramStr)
```

This gives me this result.

[Pyspark output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbEiC.png)

Yet, using scikit-learn and keras and tensorflow on the same data, all give me a straight-line result. Does LinearRegression work differently in Pyspark, or am I doing something wrong ? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: This is a great "new contributor" question.  Perfectly runnable example makes it easy to help.  Image and description of problem is even better.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the points are output in an unfortunate order.  Could the solution be a simple as sorting?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
fullPredictions.sort(col("features")).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is coming from the way that you are generating `dataset2`. You're starting with a list of tuples, which is fine, and in the `for` loop you're creating a dense array for the y values.

But the [sklearn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), state only sparse arrays, and the [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/mllib-data-types.html) state that it expects Python lists or numpy arrays.

I'd simplify dataset generation into simply arrays and retry.

Comment: @michael-west 's comment is actually a much better starting point

Comment: Morgan Bye's answer is a great second point  :) Let us know of you need help with how to simplify data generation from  arrays.

Comment: @MichaelWest  Thanks both for your comments  Unfortunately, I have come to the conclusion that PySpark LinearRegression does not return a straight-line result. I have used the PySpark Linear Regression example code here, https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-regression  Here is my test dataset
$ cat sample_linear_regression_data.txt                                                        1 1:1.0
2 1:3.0 4 1:3.0
3 1:2.0
5 1:5.0
If you run the example code on the data you can see the predictions should be on a straight-line but are not.